# How to correctly use undefined environment variables in .vimrc?

Tags: vim, environment-variables

I would like to open NERDTree at vim startup with a specific directory root depending on an environment variable.

Set environment variables will correctly be expanded, like `$HOME`. The [documentation states undefined variables will expand to an empty string](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr-env).

So this one works correctly with `NERD_TREE_ROOT` set to an existing directory. But will not if it is undefined. Instead `$NERD_TREE_ROOT` will be used like a string.

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree $HOME/$NERD_TREE_ROOT
```

How can I use undefined environment variables correctly as empty string?

EDIT: To clarify a bit. This is what I wanted to avoid:

```
if empty($NERD_TREE_ROOT)
    autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree $HOME
else
    autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree $HOME/$NERD_TREE_ROOT
endif
```

If that is not possible it will do though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you observe has nothing to do with eval or expressions: `echo eval('$HOME/$NERD_TREE_ROOT')` results in `-2147483648` just like `echo 0/0` because both variables when performing a numeric operation turn out to be zeros. The expansion of `$HOME` is performed by vim due to presence of `-complete=dir` in `:NERDTree` command definition. This is rather unexpected and, by the way, is the third type of expansion: `:echo expand('$HOME/$NERD_TREE_ROOT')` results in `$HOME/$NERD_TREE_ROOT` while `:echo expand('$HOME/$HOME')` results in `/home/zyx//home/zyx`. I do not see any way to fix this, but you can always do

```
execute 'autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree '.fnameescape($HOME.'/'.$NERD_TREE_ROOT)
```

. It is the only case when expansion works as described in the doc because it is the only way when there are any expressions.

Comment: Ah very well, exec did the trick. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 8):

Test whether it is empty before `autocmd`:

```
if !empty($NERD_TREE_ROOT)
    autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree $HOME/$NERD_TREE_ROOT
endif
```

Comment: This is what i wanted to avoid as it makes a five-liner out of an expected one-liner.

Comment: you can use **`|`(bar)** to make it one-liner